# Angular show spinner request http

Tags: angular, spinner, interceptor

I have an angular application that calls http requests. The result of these requests is passed into a behavior subject.
My need that when I have an http request running, I would like to post a spinner and hide the rest of my page
I can’t find a solution that does that
Also note that my page includes sub-components

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple solution tu that, [Pace js](https://codebyzach.github.io/pace/) an easy one but you can easily do it yourself [like this repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjcwgx?file=src%2Fapp%2Floader%2Floader.component.css). Here is the code:

```
<app-loader *ngIf="loading"></app-loader>
<div *ngIf="!loading">
    App Component, below is the child.
    <button (click)="doSomething()">Do async call</button>

    <app-child></app-child>
</div>
```

app.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  loading = false;

  doSomething() {
    this.loading = true;

    // "of(null)" is just here to simulate an http call. setTimeout simulate the time that this call took to end
    of(null).subscribe(result => {
      setTimeout(() => this.loading = false, 2000);
    });
  }
}
```

The loader comes from https://loading.io/css/

Use some css to expand your loader in full screen if you wanna be able to display this loader from any component, you'll just have to implement the same logic with `loading` true/false and the `app-loader` component in the html.

Comment: If I go something like this it makes an infinite loop to display my subcomponent that pushes an event emitter:     <div *ngIf="! (loaderService.httpProgress() | async)">

Comment: @totuti well I can't know if you don't share anything. Please provide a repro on stackblitz/codepen.

Comment: Basically I made an interceptor that triggers a spinner as soon as we get an http request. I started this spinner in spinner component that triggers on the state of the loaderService service (we see a lot of examples on the net). But I want when this component pops up, the rest of my page to be hidden

Answer (score 0):

you want child and parent component relationship by loading.

- app component and child component.
- want you to action from child or app child.

https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

app-component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-warning mb-3" (click)="load()">
    with Timeout 2 seconds
</button>
<div class="my-loader" *ngIf="isLoading"></div>
```

app-component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
    isLoading = false;
    makeHttpRequest() : void {
        this.isLoading = true;
            const subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
            subject.subscribe(
                setTimeout(() => this.isLoading = false, 4000);
            );
    }
}
```